# How to automatically generate a file from a script with current date as file name?

Tags: unix, shell

I have some shell script which generates some outputs. The output is written into a file. In my cronjob I have it:
./myscript.sh --options > output
Because the cronjob runs every week, I would like to keep a list of outputs instead of overwritting them every time the script runs. So ideally I would like to have the output file name as output_*date*. Date is current script running date. In Unix, date command can give you current date info, but how could I integrate that into the output file name?

Update:

Have tried Heath and wfaulk's methods, it does work well. However, when I put the same command in cronjob, I started to get the error:
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `)'
/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file

I know it's caused by output to a file named output_$(date +%Y%m%d) since that's the only change I made. Is there a different way to do it in cronjob?

Comment: In order to use the percents in crontab, you have to escape them with the backslash "\%"

Comment: Yeah, that worked (made a mistake earlier on while using backslash). One more thing, how do I output not only current date, but also for example a week ago? So today is Oct 5, I would like the output file being like: output_20090928_20091005. $(date +%Y%m%d) generates 20091005, how to get 20090928?

Comment: With gnu date, You can have date to "calendar math" by adding the --date parameter but instead of a numeric date you can use relative dates like:  date +Y%m%d --date "-1 week"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
myscript.sh > output_$(date +%Y%m%d)
```

Answer (score 3):

The date command does what you asked for, but [logrotate](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/117) is meant for what you are trying to do and will keep things cleaned up... It is worth learning in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

```
./myscript.sh --options > output_$(date)
```

But you probably want to use a different date format so that it doesn't have spaces and junk in it.  Something like:

```
./myscript.sh --options > output_$(date +%Y%m%d.%H%M%S)
```

On the off chance that your shell doesn't support the $() syntax, replace the `$(` and its matching `)` each with a "`` ` ``" (backtick).

Comment: Markdown: you can do <code>`</code>

Comment: Why did I think that was a block and not an inline element to the point of not even trying?

Answer (score 0):

./myscript.sh --options > output_$(date)